# SelectListGroup Name attribute issue

Tags: c#, loops, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is what I have:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> lstDailySumAssignments()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lstAssignments = new List<SelectListItem>();

        using(var context = new ConnectionString())
        {
            List<table1> lstActivity = context.table1.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();

            foreach(table1 activity in lstActivity)
            {
                SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Text = activity.text, Value = activity.ID.ToString(), Group = new SelectListGroup() { Name = activity.subcategory } };
                lstAssignments.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return lstAssignments;
    }
```

Now this all works.  The only problem is that I am using this to create a dropdownlist,and when this renders in the view it looks like this:

```
-Category 1
    -value 1
-Category 1
    -value 2
-Category 1
    -value 3
-Category 2
    -value 4
-Category 2
    -value 5
-Category 2
    -value 6
```

Instead of this:

```
-Category1
    -value 1
    -value 2
    -value 3
-Category2
    -value 4
    -value 5
    -value 6
```

I know that the `foreach` loop is causing this but I don't know how to get the `Name` property of the `SelectListGroup` to accept all and only values of 'Category', without me having to manually type in each seperate category.

So, how do I create the `SelectListGroup` outside the `foreach` loop and collect all possible `Category` Names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find all the unique categories before the for loop, and create each SelectListGroup only once for each group.
Something like this should work:

```
var groups = lstActivity.GroupBy(a => a.subcategory);
foreach (var @group in groups)
{
    var slg = new SelectListGroup() {Name = @group.Key};

    foreach (table1 activity in @group)
    {
        SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Text = activity.text, Value = activity.ID.ToString(), Group = slg };
        lstAssignments.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!